# Error handling not catching run-time error

Tags: sharepoint, vba, excel

I have a procedure that checks out a workbook from Sharepoint and then opens the workbook.  I noticed that it was generating a run-time error if the workbook has some missing required document properties, so I added some error trapping as follows:

```
Public Function getWorkbook(bkPath As String) As Workbook

Dim bk As Workbook
Dim response As Boolean

secAutomation = Application.AutomationSecurity

On Error GoTo errHandler

If Workbooks.CanCheckOut(bkPath) Then
    Workbooks.CheckOut bkPath
    Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set bk = Workbooks.Open(bkPath, False, False)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.AutomationSecurity = secAutomation
    If bk Is Nothing Then
        response = dbo_global.setStatus("error", failedToOpen)
    End If
Else
    response = dbo_global.setStatus("error", checkedout)
    Set bk = Nothing
End If
Set getWorkbook = bk
Exit Function

errHandler:
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.AutomationSecurity = secAutomation
If Not bk Is Nothing Then
    bk.Close False
    Set bk = Nothing
End If
response = dbo_global.setStatus("error", checkoutProblem)

End Function
```

`dbo_global.setStatus()` is a function for inserting entries into an Access error log.

The error is being raised at `Workbooks.CheckOut bkPath`, but instead of going to the `errHandler` block, I get an error message box:

```
Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)':    
This document cannot be checked in.
```

I want the error to be handled by closing the workbook if opened, and discarding the checkout, but I don't know how to catch the error in the `errHandler` code.

EDIT: If it helps, this is the warning message I get at the top of the workbook:

```
Required Properties
To save to the server, correct the invalid or missing required properties.
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your Visual Basic Editor settings are slightly off. In *Options*->*General*->*Error Trapping*, you need to check `Break on Unhandled Errors` - if it is `Break on All Errors`, you'll get the behavior you describe.

[image]